# Despite execution privilege, getting permission denied

Tags: permissions, executable

Compiled a binary from the golang source, but it won't execute. I tried downloading the binary, which also didn't work. Permissions all seem to be right. Running the file from go for some reason works.

Output of `~/go$ go run src/github.com/exercism/cli/exercism/main.go1`:

```
NAME:
   exercism - A command line tool to interact with http://exercism.io

USAGE:
   main [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
```

Output of `~/go/bin$ ./exercism`:

```
bash: ./exercism: Permission denied
```

Output of `~/go/bin$ ls -al`:

```
total 9932
drwxr-xr-x 2 joshua joshua     4096 Apr 28 12:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 joshua joshua     4096 Apr 28 12:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 joshua joshua 10159320 Apr 28 12:17 exercism
```

Output of `~/go/bin$ strace ./exercism`:

```
execve("./exercism", ["./exercism"], [/* 42 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Do you have execute access to the directory containing the file? You need that to `cd` into the directory in the first place, but you would get this error if you're already int he directory and the executable bit is removed.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and explain the connection between `src/github.com/exercism/cli/exercism/main.go1` and `./exercism`. In the first case, `exercism` is a directory and in the second a file.

Comment: I do have access to the directory; the error was a drive mounted with `noexec` in effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check that `noexec` is not in effect on the mount point in question. Or choose a better place to launch your script from.

```
$ mount | grep noexec
[ snip ]
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
$ cat > /dev/shm/some_script
#!/bin/sh
echo hi
$ chmod +x /dev/shm/some_script
$ /dev/shm/some_script
bash: /dev/shm/some_script: Permission denied
$ mv /dev/shm_script .
$ ./some_script
hi
```

`noexec` exists specifically to prevent security issues that come from having world-writable places storing executable files; you might put a file there, but someone else might rewrite it before you execute it, and now you're not executing the code you thought you were.

Comment: Brilliant. You're absolutely correct - I have `/home` mounted as a seperate partition with `noexec` in effect. To fix this, I would edit `/etc/fstab`, correct?

Comment: For a permanent fix, should be, yes.

For a quick fix, you should also be able to run `mount -o remount,exec /home` as root.

Comment: Update: I had in my `fstab` `LABEL=home  /home       ext4    defaults,user    0   2
`; user implies no exec. I changed it to `defaults ` and rebooted, now it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to Accept the answer. ;)